# Managed bean not working after adding Spring configuration

Tags: spring, jsf-2

I really do not know what's the cause of the problem. I created a website with hibenate and JSF and later decided to integrate Spring framework as well, but eventually faced a problem.

My managed bean "loginbean" was working perfectly. It also recognizes the method within a JSF page, but when I run the application I see an "error excusion" message.

My bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {

    private String username;  

    private String password; 

    private int activeindex;

    public String Dirige(int a){
       setActiveindex(a);
       if (a == 0){
           return "/Menu.jsf"; 
       }else{
       if (a == 1) {
              return "/pagess/pagesFabricant/Fabricant.jsf";
           }else{
              if (a == 2) {
                 return "/pagess/pagesComposant/Composant.jsf";
              }else{
                  if(a == 3){
                      return "/pagess/pagesDeq/DEQ.jsf";
                  }

              }
           }
       }
       return null; 
   }
}
```

I added `SpringBeanFacesELResolver` in faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application> on faces.config.xml
```

and I also included the relevant listeners in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/application.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

My view:

```
<p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{loginBean.activeindex}">  
    <p:menuitem value="Home"  icon="ui-icon-star" action="#{loginBean.Dirige(0)}" />
    <p:menuitem value="Fabricants"  icon="ui-icon-wrench"   action="#{loginBean.Dirige(1)}" /> 
    <p:menuitem value="Composants" icon="ui-icon-search"  action="#{loginBean.Dirige(2)}"/> 
    <p:menuitem value="Dossier d'equivalence"  icon="ui-icon-document" action="#{loginBean.Dirige(3)}"/> 
</p:tabMenu>
```

And finally this is the error I've got:

```
Grave: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /templates/template.xhtml @42,95 action="#{loginBean.Dirige(1)}": Method not found: com.ardia.beans.LoginBean@1af73b2.Dirige(java.lang.Long)
javax.faces.el.MethodNotFoundException: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /templates/template.xhtml @42,95 action="#{loginBean.Dirige(1)}": Method not found: com.ardia.beans.LoginBean@1af73b2.Dirige(java.lang.Long)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:92)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
```

Comment: Just one thing I don't understund it ..whay when I eleminate dirige(int a){ setindex(a) }  ,by another methode diride0(){setindex(0)} it work corect ...with not parameter on parenthes !!!!! it was like that without spring !!!

Comment: Your method starts with an uppercase D, I would fix that first.

Comment: Your exception clearly indicates that the parameter you're passing is a `Long` and the method in your backing bean accepts an `int`.

Comment: If you use JBoss AS, try removing JBoss EL "org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl" from web.xml

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that ***I start the application in another tomcat server*** .. it works well it accepts bean method with parameters

Thx all for your cooperation